# c++ Receiving “-nan.(ind)” from output instead of a number?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double* cal1(double* all1)
{
    int t,count=0;
    ifstream srcFile("in.txt", ios::in); 
    if (!srcFile) 
    { 
        cout << "error opening source file." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    char x;
    while (srcFile >> x) 
    {
        t = x - 'a' ;
        count++;
        if (t >= 0 && t <= 25)
            all1[t]++;
        else
            all1[26]++;
    }
    all1[27] =count ;
    srcFile.close();
   /* for (t = 0; t <= 26; t++)
        {
        cout << all1[t] / all1[27]<<endl;
        }
    cout << all1[27] << endl;*/
    return all1;
}
double finalcal1(double* all)
{
    int t;
    double p,cal1=0;
    for (t = 0; t <= 26; t++)
    {
        p = (all[t] / all[27]);
        all[t] = p * log(p);
    }
    for (t = 0; t <= 26; t++)
    {
        cal1 -= all[t];
    }
    return cal1;
}

int main()
{
    double  *all =new double[28];        //1
    double t;
    all = cal1(all);
    t = finalcal1(all);
    cout << t << endl;
    delete[] all;
    return 0;
}

    enter code here
```

instead of receiving a number from the result, I just got a “-nan.(ind)” which is not even a number. Besides, when I change the number from mark 1 to *all =new double[27] which is what it supposed to be, there would be error or bugs showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double  *all =new double[28];
```

You probably want to initialise all these values to zero to start with since, otherwise, they'll have arbitrary values.

And, if those arbitrary values consist of any `NaN` items, that will propagate when you add things to them, or divide by some count.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
double *all = new double[28]();
```

You may also want to consider the possibility that `log(x)` is not actually defined for all values of `x` (such as zero or negative values) - that may be *another* way in which you could get a `NaN`.

Comment: No need for that loop. Just use the constructor call syntax — `new double[28]()`; and in general you could of course use `std::fill`. But I guess before that we’d replace the raw pointer array with a `std::vector`.